# collapse search bar to icon in Boot strap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a responsive layout in Boot Strap 3.

I am not able to fix the collapsible search bar. Please click on below link to view the how collapsible menu should look.

**Expanded Menu Link**
[image]

**Collapsible Menu Link**
[image]

Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: What is the actual issue? Can you provide a demo/code ?

Comment: The actual issue is that not able to convert search bar into search icon and cart into Cart icon in collapsible mode

Comment: Please add a demo in http://jsfiddle.net or http://bootply.com/new So that I can understand better

Comment: Can find code @http://idea66.com/mobile/index.htm

Comment: What code did you wrote to get the desired result? I see nothing on your page?

Comment: Hey Surjit, don't know how to add break points to get desired result (collapsible one) in boot strap. I just wrote code for expanded one

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code a little bit to make it work on mobile device.

Change this

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/iconCart.png" width="14" height="13"> 
Cart <span class="badge">2</span></a>
```

To this

```
<a href="#">
<span class="show-mobile"><img src="images/iconCart.png" width="14" height="13"> </span>
<span class="hidden-mobile">Cart</span> 
<span class="badge hidden-mobile">2</span> 
</a>
```

And add media Query CSS like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.show-mobile {
 display:inline-block;
}

.hidden-mobile {
display:none;
}

}
```